# what is the general solution of the given differential equation

Tags: differential

$$
2\cdot (x+1)\cdot y′′(x) −(x+1)\cdot y′(x) +2\cdot y(x) = 0
$$
This is the differential equation.
then how can i calculate the general solution that is valid in any interval not including the singular point.

Comment: Is it $[ 2(x+1) D^{2} - (x+1) D + 2] y = 0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This differential equation
$$2\cdot (x+1)\cdot y′′(x) −(x+1)\cdot y′(x) +2\cdot y(x) = 0$$
is indeed a very difficult one and I did not find any way helping to find its general solution. Hoping that it could help you in your search of a solution, I used a CAS and arrived to
$$y(x)=(x-3) (x+1) \left(c_2 \text{Ei}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)+c_1\right)-2 c_2
   e^{\frac{x+1}{2}} (x-1)$$ which is defined for all values of $x$.

However, the writing of the original post was not very clear and the  differential equation could have been
$$ (x+1)^2\cdot y′′(x) −(x+1)\cdot y′(x) +2\cdot y(x) = 0$$ which is slightly easier and for which the solution write $$y(x)=(x+1) \left(c_1 \sin (\log (x+1))+c_2 \cos (\log (x+1))\right)$$ which is defined for all $x \geq -1$

Answer (score 0):

A proof of the result reported by Claude Lebovici :
$$y(x)=(x-3) (x+1) \left(c_2 \text{Ei}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)+c_1\right)-2 c_2
   e^{\frac{x+1}{2}} (x-1)$$ 
is shown below :
[image]